# rCharts - date in x axis

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts

I am trying to plot a graph using rCharts library.Problem is on x-axis instead of date, timestamp is coming.

My data frame is:

[image]

Code is:

```
h <- getChart(chartType)
lineWidth <- 2
colors <- c('#2F9BE4', '#349A34', '#B44545')
h$title(text = "OnlineUsers and Load Average")
h$xAxis(categories = userLoadData$timestamp)
h$yAxis(title = list(text = 'Numbers'), opposite = FALSE)
h$series(data = userLoadData$viewingVideos, name="Students watching Video", lineWidth=lineWidth, color=colors[[1]], marker=list(radius = 0), zoneAxis = 'x', zones=list(c(value = last),  c(dashStyle = "dot")))
return (h)
```

Finally, my chart looks as follows. As you can see instead of date timestamp is coming there

[image]

Update: Converting userLoadData$timestamp to date using as.Date() and putting (type = 'datetime') worked

Comment: A [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1261281) would help us help you

Comment: It looks that you have set your xAxis to categories, have you tried using datetime type of your xAxis instead? (type = 'datetime')

Comment: Converting  userLoadData$timestamp to date using as.Date() and putting (type = 'datetime')  worked.